# Get radio value on label click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got an example of my problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LWcu8/1/

How can I get the current radio button I've clicked instead of the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $(".options > label").live("click", function(event)
  {
    radio_value = $(this).prev("input[type='radio']").val();
    $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
  });
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/LWcu8/11/

Comment: Thank you, the key is using "prev".

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".options > label").live("click", function(event)
{
    radio_value = $(this).prev(":radio").val();
    $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/LWcu8/3/)

If you want to use jQuery > 1.7 then you can do it like following:

```
$(".options").on("click", "label", function(event)
{
    radio_value = $(this).prev(":radio").val();
    $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/LWcu8/12/)

#### Note

you need `.prev()` because you bind the click event to `label` and `radio` it its previous element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".options > label").live("click", function(event)
{
    radio_value = $("#" + $(this).attr('for')).val();
    $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LWcu8/6/**

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying the callback:

```
$(".options > label").live("click", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        radio_value = $("input[name='size']:checked").val();
        $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
    }, 0)();
});​
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LWcu8/16/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".options > input[name='size']").live("click", function(event)
{
    radio_value = $(this).val();
    $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
});​
```

Your code binds the label's click event, which occurs before you get the radio's value.  You should just bind the input[name='size'] and then it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to:

```
$("input[name='size']").live("change", function(event)
{
    radio_value = $("input[name='size']:checked").val();
    $("#clicked").html(radio_value);
});​
```

The `click` event is fired on the label, before the change to the radio buttons occurs. So you should respond to the change instead.